# How to count the occurrence of a string in a column depending on value in other column using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the following data frame:

```
     MV_STATUS   SEX
0        0        F
1        1        M
2        1        F
3        0        M
4        1        M
5        0        F
6        1        M
```

I am trying to define a variable (nmv_fem) as the count of the occurrence of 'F' in the 'SEX' column ONLY when 'MV_STATUS' in the corresponding row is '0'.

Ideally, upon successfully defining the variable, print(nvm_fem) would simply return '2', as 'F' only occurs twice in the 'SEX' column when 'MV_STATUS' is also '0'.

I have failed trying many variations of the following:

```
nmv_fem = self.df.df.loc[self.df.df['MV_STATUS'] == 0][self.df.df['SEX'] == 'F'].sum()
```

How might I achieve this?

Comment: `len(df[df["MV_STATUS"] & df["SEX"] == "F"])`

Answer (score 1):

```py
nmv_fem = df.query('MV_STATUS == 0')['SEX'].value_counts()['F']
```

Comment: This seems over-engineered.

Comment: Yup, not much to do these days. By the way, you misplaces a ']' in your comment.

Comment: Thanks a ton, Bishwarup. This is exactly what I was looking to do. Sorry that I am a bit too new and without a strong enough reputation to publicly up vote your answer.